# add 18 hours to getdate() result

Tags: sql, datetime, scalar

I'm trying to get yesterdays date on 18:00:00 time.

I've tried this:

```
DECLARE @YesturdayDate datetime = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()-1));

select dateadd(h,18,@YesturdayDate)
```

but i'm getting an error when run the select statement:

"Must declare the scalar variable "@YesturdayDate". "

why is that?

thanks.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using? I assume 2005.

Answer (score 3):

What version of sql-server are you using? I assume 2005, then you cannot iniitalize a variable in the same line you have declared it.

```
DECLARE @YesturdayDate datetime;
SET @YesturdayDate = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()-1));

select dateadd(hh,18,@YesturdayDate);
```

(you also have to use `dateadd(hh...` instead of `dateadd(h...` )

Comment: On 2005, it would produce 2 errors, the first of which is quite explanatory "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable". I'd have hoped the OP would mention that error if it was occurring or already resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair:

```
DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010102',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T18:00:00')
```

This exploits the relationship between two constant datetime values. It's "add the whole number of days that have elapsed between 2nd January 2001 and right now to 18:00 on the 1st January 2001". Which is the same as "give me 18:00 yesterday".

---

As to the original error you report - if it's the *only* error that's occurring, the only thing I can think is that your two statements are actually in separate batches (separated from each other by a `GO` command)